# (MySQLi Procedural) INSERT INTO (...) WHERE ID = SESSION ID

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to insert data into MySQL database, the column where the data should be inserted must depend on the session ID.

```php
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST["mybutton"])) {

    $favcolor = $_POST["mybutton"];

    switch ($favcolor) {
        case "0":
            $sql = "INSERT INTO preferences (color) VALUES ('colord_id_1') WHERE id = $_SESSION['id']";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            break;
        case "1":
            $sql = "INSERT INTO preferences (color) VALUES ('colord_id_2') WHERE id = $_SESSION['id']";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            break;
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: There is no `INSERT INTO ... WHERE`. Either you insert the id, or you update the row. So the question is, is there already a row with that ID? Or do you wish to insert a new row with that ID?

Comment: The ID already exists, (id, email, password, color, etc), ID is incremental, thus I want to insert that data in the ID of the particular user.

Comment: You could even avoid the long switch statement altogether by using array.

Comment: Just to make sure, show us the schema for your `preferences` table

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think OP knows his code produces error, but he was trying to solve the problem himself anyway.

Comment: It is the wrong approach IMHO. The setting "color" is most likely tied to a User (and his ID in the database). A session, as well as a session id, is volatile and session_id regeneration is a very common method to counter session fixation attacks. 
Or when the session expires and isn't picked up again, it will eventually being garbage collected and the session id is gone forever. Only the record in your database remains as garbage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update the record instead of inserting new one:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE preferences SET color='colord_id_1' WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Procedural style:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE preferences SET color='colord_id_1' WHERE id=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $_SESSION['id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Thanks, works like charm! How would that be done in Procedural style?

Comment: @IskrenLalov See my update. Procedural style is more verbose and it is easier to make mistakes. I would recommend to use OOP style, but if you prefer procedural then it will work too.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will take it into consideration!